# Select NSTableView row programmatically and call method

Tags: selection, nstableview, nsindexset

I have an NSTableView that I add objects to (through core data). I came across this in my searches:

```
NSIndexSet *indexSet = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:1];
[tableView selectRowIndexes:indexSet byExtendingSelection:NO];
```

which works, but the problem is when I replace 1 with `[myarray count]` it doesn't select the last row.

My second question is when I have an IBAction hooked up to the table view to automatically call it when a row is selected, what is the sender?  **EDIT: Solved this one thanks to a good old NSLog**

Comment: try to log `[myarray count]` and compare with your table datasource `-(NSInteger)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView` return value

Comment: @vince they're both returning the same value, the row just isn't being selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question indexes are normally zero based. If I have

```
| row 0 | row 1 | row 2  |   row 3    |
| item 1| item 2| item 3 | item 4 |
```

The count will be `4` but the last index will be `3`.

I'm not sure on the second answer I only know iOS at the moment.

Comment: well all be darn, that's it!, I just had add `-1` to the end and it works!